# Multiple styles in TextField, JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, textfield

I would like to have a textfield with multiple styling on different words as I process it.

E.g. upon detection of a keyword, set the font color to red.

I am aware of the **RichTextFx** library that I can use. However, the nodes are mostly for text areas which is not what I want.

I have thought about styling the textarea such that it looks like a textfield, but I would preferably not do that.

May I know of any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot style text inside a TextField.

Comment: I am aware of that. That's why I am asking if there's any way like how RichTextFX made styling available for text areas. Will it be able to style for textfields? or do I have to find workarounds

Comment: RichText is a `custom control`. It is **not inherited** from TextArea. You can think of it as a new TextArea which is written from scratch :)